# TypeError: list indicies must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm sort of new to coding, as I didn't get taught properly in school, so I'm trying to learn outside of school. And this is my code of a Menu.

```
Sauces = ("\nSauces: \n Cranberry Sauce \n Barbecue Sauce \n Brown Sauce \n Horseradish \n Hot Sauce \n Mayonnaise \n Mustard \n Ketchup \n No Sauce")
Starters = ("\nStarters: \n Calamary \n Chilli Prawn Bruschetta \n Chicken Satay \n 5 Chicken Drumsticks \n Smoked Salmon Cocktial \n Backed Mushrooms With Festive Cheese \n Soup Served In Bread \n Arancini \n Garlic Bread")

while True:
    try:
        NumberPeople = int(input("How many people are here today? "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry I didn't understand that. Please try again.")
        continue

    if NumberPeople < 0:
        print("Sorry, you cannot have negative amount of people.")
        continue

    if NumberPeople < 1:
        print("Sorry, you cannot have nobody coming.")
        continue
    
    else:
        break

if NumberPeople < 3:
    print("Thank you. There is a table free for you at Table 2")
elif NumberPeople < 5:
    print("Thank you. There is a table free for you at Table 1")
elif NumberPeople < 7:
    print("Thank you. There is a table free for you at Table 3")
elif NumberPeople < 21:
    print("Thank you. There is a table free for you at Table 8")
else:
    print("Sorry we don't have enough space for that many people")




print(Starters)
MyOrder = []
for i in range(NumberPeople):
    while True:
        try:
            StarterMenu = input ("\nPerson %i, what would you like? " % (i + 1))
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry I didn't understand. Please try again.")
            continue
        if StarterMenu == "Calamary":
            print(Sauces)
            SauceChoice = input("\nWhat sauce do you want? ")
            if SauceChoice == "Cranberry Sauce":
                MyOrder.append("Calamary with Cranberry Sauce")
                break
            elif SauceChoice == "Barbecue Sauce":
                MyOrder.append("Calamary with Barbecue Sauce")
                break
            elif SauceChoice == "Brown Sauce":
                MyOrder.append("Calamary with Brown Sauce")
                break
            elif SauceChoice == "Horseradish":
                MyOrder.append("Calamary with Horseradish")
                break
            elif SauceChoice == "Hot Sauce":
                MyOrder.append("Calamary with Hot Sauce")
                break
            elif SauceChoice == "Mayonnaise":
                MyOrder.append("Calamary with Mayonnaise")
                break
            elif SauceChoice == "Mustard":
                MyOrder.append("Calamary with Mustard")
                break
            elif SauceChoice == "Ketchup":
                MyOrder.append("Calamary with Ketchup")
                break
            elif SauceChoice == "No Sauce":
                MyOrder.append("Calamary with No Sauce")
                break
            else:
                print("Sorry I didn't understand. Please try again")
                continue
        else:
            print("Okay No Starter")
```

All of the stuff above seems to run smooth, but it's the code below that runs into the problem that I seem to not understand. I looked at this website and I saw I should use this way, but when I do it, I get ***TypeError: list indicies must be integers or slices, not str.***

```
    print ("Order is being processed, next order:\n")
    MyOrder.append({ 'SauceChoice': SauceChoice })

print('The orders has been processed with these data:')
for i in range(NumberPeople):
    order = MyOrder[i]
    print (' - Person', i + 1, 'wants ', StarterMenu, 'with %i ' % MyOrder['SauceChoice'])
```

Comment: Well, the error is pretty clear about the problem. `MyOrder` is a list, and you try to index it with `['SauceChoice']` but list indices can only be ints (`[0]`, `[1]`, etc.). What did you expect `MyOrder['SauceChoice']` to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
print (' - Person', i + 1, 'wants ', StarterMenu, 'with %i ' % MyOrder['SauceChoice'])
```

MyOrder is defined as a list. You have to specify the index of the key 'SauceChoice' when you are trying to access the value of SauceChoice.

Comment: How do I specify SauceChoice?

Comment: you can get the index of an element in the list using list.index(element).
In your case ```MyOrder[MyOrder.index('SauceChoice')] ``` should give you what you are looking for.
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index - see this for reference

Comment: When I try that, I get "ValueError: 'SauceChoice' is not in list". That didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
MyOrder['SauceChoice']
```

You are using a string as an index instead of the integer variable `SauceChoice`. Strings are not legal indexes for lists/tuples.